# How to load new view in the same window on button click?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch

I've got the View-Controller with a button. I want the new view to be loaded over my **View-Controller** when the button is pressed. It'd not replace the existing view, I want it to be smaller than the screen and hide when I tap out of the small view.

How should it be implemented in code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
- (IBAction)button:(id)sender 
{
UIView *view2=[[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,200,200)];
[self.view addSubview:view2];
UITapGestureRecognizer *Tap = [[[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(Tapview)] autorelease];
[view2 addGestureRecognizer:Tap];
}

-(void)Tapview
{
[view2 removeFromSuperview];
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, your answer helped, but one little question. I want view2 to close when I tap out of it, and your snippet closes view2 when I tap on it. How can I change it?

Comment: so you can use `[self.view addGestureRecognizer:Tap]` method instead of `[view2 addGestureRecognizer:Tap]` method in above code.
}

Answer (score 2):

Add Tap Gesture to self.view like this:

```
 UITapGestureRecognizer *oneFinger = 
 [[[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(oneFingerAction:)] autorelease];

// Set required taps and number of touches
[oneFinger setNumberOfTapsRequired:1];
[oneFinger setNumberOfTouchesRequired:1];

// Add the gesture to the view
[[self view] addGestureRecognizer:oneFinger];
```

Add one BOOL flag in .h file; in ViewDidLoad method add this:

```
 flag = FALSE;
```

Now I assume u have UIView *smallView which be added on screen like this:

```
[self.view addSubView:smallView];
flag = TRUE;
smallView.center = self.view.centre;
```

Now when tapped on self.view tap gesture action called

```
- (void)oneFingerAction:(UITapGestureRecognizer*)sender
{
   if(sender.view == self.view)
   { 
     if(flag){
       if(smallView)
       {
         [smallView removeFromSuperView];
       }
     }
   }
}
```